# How to add a record to __EFMigrationsHistory without actually running the migration in EF Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an issue where I have an existing database which where I have mapped over only certain entities to use with EF Core (the DB has 100s of tables and I dont want classes for all of them.

I scaffolded the starting stage like this

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold .. etc etc
```

Where I specified specific tables with the connection string.

I then created an initial migration to snapshot the starting stage with

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial
```

I now want to add a new table based on a new entity. So I created a second migration using

```
dotnet ef migrations add NewTable
```

But when i run this using..

```
dotnet ef database update NewTable
```

It attempts to add the tables in the initial migration! because I havent ran that migration, so I have no records in __EFMigrationsHistory. But I dont want to run the first migration as I already have the tables which were scaffolded! Initial was just to create a snapshot which is what I thought you have to do.

So is there some way to make it think Initial has already been run? By putting something in 
__EFMigrationsHistory? Then I can run the NewTable migration without getting "object already exisits".

Thanks

Comment: Can't you insert the pending migration name into `__EFMigrationsHistory` manually?

Comment: I did but I had the same issue. It finally worked when I deleted the initial migration code file.. that was still trying to generate tables even though I wasn't running it.. adding a record to __EFMigrationsHistory made no difference. It still tried to run the first migration till I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

It ran my latest NewTable migration fine after I removed the previous one, otherwise it was still trying to add objects from the initial migration resulting in "Object already exists".

I find this strange as the statement 
'dotnet ef database update NewTable'
specifies which migration I wanted to run, and shouldn't run initial again. Anyway this fix worked fine.

Comment: `dotnet ef database update NewTable` runs all needed migrations to bring the database into the state described by the history of migrations up to the given one. It can also downgrade your database with removing migrations. If you have 5 migrations, your databse is on "migration 4" and you run "...update 3", migration number 4 will get reverted. The state of applied migrations are tracked inside the table __EFMigrationsHistory. You can manually insert/delete rows to let dotnet-ef do, what you want.